# call python from jquery, cannot get POST params

Tags: jquery, python, post

Below is the javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/vote_selection/vote/',
  dataType:'json',
  data: {'message':'123'},
  success:function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Below is the python code:

```
def vote_select(request):
    print "1"
    print request
    print request.method
    print request.POST
    return HttpResponse("1",mimetype='text/plain')
```

And the output is

1

,
POST:,
...
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
..

GET

[29/Sep/2012 22:38:49] "GET /vote_selection/vote/ HTTP/1.0" 200 1

Why does the method become GET and why is there no params in either GET or POST?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
import json    
def vote_select(request):
        print "1"
        print request
        print request.method
        print request.POST
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({ 'somevalue': 1 }),mimetype='application/json')
```